# Updating Software on Debian to non packaged version

Tags: debian, package-management, compiling, touch-screen

The most current `xf86-input-wacom` version on Debian is 2 years old (0.34.99.1-1) it seems like and there is a bug where the touchscreen would not work spontaneously anymore which is fixed in version 0.36.1. I now obviously want that version on my Debian (currently still Buster, but I could update). Is building the package acceptable and will it be invincible to updates, or will a single update cause the whole thing to break down? In that case, should I just stay at Debian Buster, because its frozen? I know I am creating a "franken Debian" by doing that, so how to do it the correct Debian way without causing to much trouble?

**Handy Links I found so far:**
https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/349/
https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/xf86-input-wacom
https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to upgrade a package to a newer version which isn’t packaged yet, without risking the upgraded version being overwritten by a new package:

- package the new version yourself, or build an updated source package (in this case, Ubuntu has a package of version 0.36);
- uninstall the package and install from source.

The former is far more “Debian-like”.

However, in your particular scenario, the best solution might be to stop using `xf86-input-wacom` altogether: `libinput` supports Wacom touchscreens, and has better multitouch support. It will handle the touchscreen automatically once the Wacom driver is removed.

If `libinput` doesn’t work, the best way to get an updated Wacom driver without resorting to a FrankenDebian is to *rebuild* the driver:

- install some tools we’ll need

  ```
  sudo apt install build-essential devscripts
  ```
- retrieve the Ubuntu source package

  ```
  dget -ux https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/xf86-input-wacom/1:0.36.1-0ubuntu2/xf86-input-wacom_0.36.1-0ubuntu2.dsc
  ```
- go into the extracted directory

  ```
  cd xf86-input-wacom*
  ```
- create a package to represent the build dependencies (this will make cleanup easier)

  ```
  mk-build-deps debian/control
  ```
- install it

  ```
  sudo apt install ./*build-deps*.deb
  ```
- move it out of the way

  ```
  mv ./*build-deps*.deb ..
  ```
- build the package

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```
- install the generated packages

  ```
  sudo debi
  ```
- clean up

  ```
  sudo apt --autoremove purge xf86-input-wacom-build-deps xserver-xorg-input-wacom-dbgsym
  ```

Comment: I though libinput is the library for wayland? Should I then try to switch to wayland? I think my hardware might be compatible, but touchegg doesn't work on wayland, does it?

Comment: libinput works with X.org too (on top of the evdev driver).

Comment: I have problems with my stylus when using libinput, so thats not an option. I will try updating the package and then acceptyour answer if it worked

Comment: I used the Ubuntu package and updated the libc6 library to testing and it worked. Don't know about updates now, still... As I now have offically created a franken debian by mixing important librarys from stable and testing

Comment: I’ve added detailed build instructions so you can install the new package without resorting to a FrankenDebian.